# Access - Match Column Range / Complex Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How do we match columns based on condition of closeness to value.
This requires Complex Query / Range Comparison / Multiple Joins conditions. 
Getting Query size exceeded 2GB error.

Tables :

```
InvDetails1 / InvDetails2 / INVDL / ExpectedResult
```

Field Relation :

```
InvDetails1.F1 = InDetails2.F3

InvDetails2.F5 = INVDL.F1

INVDL.DLID = ExpectedResult.DLID

ExpectedResult.Total - 1 <  InvDetails1.F6 < ExpectedResult.Total + 1

left(InvDetails1.F21,10) = '2013-03-07'
```

Return Results where Number of records from ExpectedResult is only 1.

```
Group by InvDetails1.F1 , count(ExpectedResult.DLID) works.
```

From this result.

Final Result :

```
InvDetails1.F1 , InvDetails1.F16 , ExpectedResult.DLID , ExpectedResult.NMR

ExpectedResult - has millions of rows.
InvDetails - few hundred thousands
```

Comment: What is the full query that is causing the problem?

Comment: Really, you have column names `F1..F6`?  Change those to mean something and life will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was in that situation and was finding that my query was "hitting a wall" at 2GB then one thing I would try would be to create a separate saved Select Query to isolate the `InvDetails1` records *just for the specific date in question*. Then I would use that query instead of the full `InvDetails1` table when joining to the other tables.

My reasoning is that the query optimizer may not be able to use your `left(InvDetails1.F21,10) = '2013-03-07'` condition to exclude `InvDetails1` records early in the execution plan, possibly causing the query to grow much larger than it really needs to (internally, while it is being processed). Forcing the date selection to the beginning of the process by putting it in a separate (prerequisite) query may keep the size of the "main" query down to a more feasible size.

Also, if I found myself in the situation where my queries were getting that big I would also keep a watchful eye on the size of my .accdb (or .mdb) file to ensure that *it* does not get too close to 2GB. I've never had it happen myself, but I've heard that database files that hit the 2GB barrier can result in some nasty errors and be rather "challenging" to recover.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am going to try that now. I am really starting to respect you SO much , for the continuous help you have been giving me throughout.
How do we perform a Join with ExpectedResult from the query based ont + / - 1 clause , can that be put on a ON condition.

Comment: @arcotenterprises re: +/-1 - `ON (InvDetails1.F6 > ExpectedResult.Total - 1) AND (InvDetails1.F6 < ExpectedResult.Total + 1)` should work.

Comment: SELECT qInvDETAILSDatedRegion.F1 AS Expr1
FROM (ExpectedResult INNER JOIN InvDL ON ExpectedResult.DLID = InvDL.DLID) INNER JOIN qInvDETAILSDatedRegion ON ( (qInvDETAILSDatedRegion.F6 +1 > ExpectedResult.Total ) and ( qInvDETAILSDatedRegion.F6 -1 < ExpectedResult.Total  ) ) AND (InvDL.RegionCode = qInvDETAILSDatedRegion.F5);

qInvDETAILSDatedRegion - fetches the date part results from InvDetails1 and InvDetails2.
seems to be the query , it starts displaying the result , but does not end (do not get the final count below in access for quite a long time.